# MS Access error: Cant Add All of the Records in the Updte or Append Query -

Tags: ms-access

i researched the knowledge base for this MS Access error I'm getting, but didn't find the answer i needed.
I am using a query to Make a table.   When it runs, I get the following error:
MS Access error: Cant Add All of the Records in the Updte or Append Query:  It set 8 Fields to Null due to a type conversion error.   I can understand getting this error if i am trying to Update or append a table, but this query is MAKING a table, so I don't understand why there would be a conversion error.

Thank you anyone who can help me
[image: MSACCESS ERROR MESSAGE]

here is the Query - in SQL format:

```
    SELECT CrossWalk.Customer_Seq_Num AS Seq, CrossWalk.THG_Description AS [THG Description], CrossWalk.Merit_Item_Num AS [Merit ID#], Merit.Description AS [Description-Merit], Merit.[Unit Meas#] AS [U/M-Merit], Merit.[Pack Size] AS [Pkg Size-Merit], Merit.[Unit Price] AS [Price-Merit], CrossWalk.Factor_Merit AS [Merit Factor], IIf([CrossWalk]![Factor_Merit]>0,Round(([Merit]![Unit Price]/[CrossWalk]![Factor_Merit]),2),0) AS [PricePer-Merit], Merit.Weight AS Weight, CrossWalk.USFood_Item AS [USFood ID#], USFoods.[Product Desc] AS [Description-USF], USFoods.[Product UOM] AS [U/M-USF], CrossWalk.Factor_USFoods AS [Factor-USF], USFoods.[Product Package Size] AS [Pkg Size-USF], USFoods.[Product Price] AS [Price-USF], IIf([CrossWalk]![Factor_USFoods]>0,Round([USFoods]![Product Price]/[CrossWalk]![Factor_USFoods],2),0) AS [Price-Per USF], CrossWalk.ShamRock_Item_Num, Shamrock.Description AS [Description-Shamrock], Shamrock.Unit AS [U/M-Sham], CrossWalk.Factor_Shamrock AS [Factor-Sham], Shamrock.[Pack Size] AS [Pkg Size-Sham], Shamrock.Price AS [Price-Sham], IIf([CrossWalk]![Factor_Shamrock]>0,Round([Shamrock]![Price]/[CrossWalk]![Factor_Shamrock],2),0) AS [Price-Per Sham], CrossWalk.SysCo_Item_Num AS SUPC, Sysco.Desc AS [Description-Sysco], Sysco.Unit AS [U/M-Sysco], CrossWalk.Factor_SysCo AS [Factor-Sysco], Sysco.Pack AS [Qty-Sysco], Sysco.Size AS [Sysco -Size], Sysco.[Case $] AS [Sysco-Case $], Sysco.[Split $] AS [Sysco-Split$], IIf([CrossWalk]![Factor_SysCo]>0,Round([Sysco]![Case $]/[CrossWalk]![Factor_SysCo],2),0) AS [Price-Per Sysco], RestDepot.Item AS [RestDepot Item], RestDepot.Description AS [RestDepot-Desc], RestDepot.[U/M] AS [RestDepot-UnitMeas], RestDepot.[Est#Price] AS [RestDepot- Est Price], CrossWalk.Factor_RestDepot AS [RestDepot-Factor], IIf([CrossWalk]![Factor_RestDepot]>0,Round([RestDepot]![Est#Price]/[CrossWalk]![Factor_RestDepot],2),0) AS [RestDepot-Price-Per] INTO [COMPARE SPREADSHEET]
FROM RestDepot RIGHT JOIN (Merit RIGHT JOIN (USFoods RIGHT JOIN (Sysco RIGHT JOIN (Shamrock RIGHT JOIN CrossWalk ON Shamrock.[Product #] = CrossWalk.ShamRock_Item_Num) ON Sysco.SUPC = CrossWalk.SysCo_Item_Num) ON USFoods.[Product Number] = CrossWalk.USFood_Item) ON Merit.[Item Number] = CrossWalk.Merit_Item_Num) ON RestDepot.[Item] = CrossWalk.RestDepot_Item_Num
WHERE (((CrossWalk.THG_Description) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY CrossWalk.Customer_Seq_Num;
```

Comment: You are trying to make a table with a query that joins a lot of tables. It's hard to tell from that graphic what is joined to what. Could rearrange the tables so fields and join lines are clearly displayed then post that graphic. Will a SELECT query work with those joins and all expected records are retrieved?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!   What is odd to me is that the query works when it is running a selection.

Comment: I doubt anyone can answer your question without being able to directly analyze db data and relationships. Attachment type fields cannot be included in make table SQL but I would expect a different error message. Should probably post in a forum that facilitates attaching files.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion. I tried amending the post, but didn't see an option to upload the MS ACCESS file.  Can you reference where i would find this option?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't upload files on SO. Images can be embedded but that's it. That's why I suggested going to another forum like accessforums.net, access-programmers.co.uk, utteraccess.com

Comment: thank you very much!